# BooleanField doesn't work (always checked) in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django

I use BooleanField in my model like this:

active = models.BooleanField()

During edition in django admin, attribute 'active' is always checked, why?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default it shows as active i.e checked/True.

If you want NULL value as well try using `NullBooleanField`

Comment: I write about EDIT model object. If model object is inactive, atributte 'active' shouldn't be showed as active (checked checkbox).

Comment: @DavidSilva So in admin you save object with this checkbox not selected and it again shows as selected? What goes in DB?